# Assembly - Trouble checking a string for non-numbers

Tags: string, delphi, assembly

I'm trying to make a simple program that loops through a string and increments a register if any character isn't the in characters 0-9.

There are no syntax errors or anything, but the output is sporadic and changes each time I run it. So basically, it doesn't work because it doesn't output what is expected.

I'm using the 'asm' functionality of Delphi to write this, so variables are defined outside of the ASM code.

This is my code as I have it:

```
function checkInteger(numIn : String) : Boolean;
var isValid : Boolean;
  lengthOfString,incorrectCharacters,count: integer;
  buffer: integer;
begin

lengthOfString := length(numIn);
buffer := 0;

//BEGIN ASSEMBLY

asm
    xor edx,edx
    lea ecx,[numIn]
    mov [count],ecx

    @next:
    mov ecx,[count]
    movzx eax,byte[ecx]


    inc ecx
    mov [count],ecx

    cmp eax,'0'
    jb @increase_incorrect
    cmp eax,'9'
    ja @increase_incorrect

    jmp @skip

    @increase_incorrect:
    inc edx

    @skip:

    mov ecx,[lengthOfString]
    sub ecx,1
    mov [lengthOfString],ecx
    cmp ecx,0
    jg @next
    mov [incorrectCharacters],edx

end;

//END ASSEMBLY

if(incorrectCharacters > 0) then begin
  isValid := true;
end else begin
  isValid := false;
end;

checkInteger := isValid;
end;
```

The 'numIn' variable is just a user entered string containing any valid characters. As a note, the string will never be empty as I check for that earlier in the program.

Comment: How can you tell that your asm isn't stomping on important registers? Mixing asm and pascal in one routine is playing with fire.  No idea why you want to use asm here. Why won't you show a complete program? That way nobody needs to guess. Also, `isValid := incorrectCharacters > 0;` is how to write that.

Comment: You must save ESI.  Only EAX, EDX and ECX are allowed to be modified in `asm` blocks in Delphi.

Comment: Is it worth the effort coding this in asm? If the only thing you want to check is if "any" character is invalid, jump out at first miss.

Comment: There is no specific reason I'm coding this in ASM, I could do the same in 2 minutes with straight pascal, however that's not the point. The reason I'm doing this in ASM is purely for the fun of it because I enjoy the challenge. Also, the inability to edit the ESI register is interesting, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Could any of your values be negative ? i.e., are any of the bytes in your target string in the range of 80h to 0FFh ?  If so, the `jl @increase_incorrect` and the `jg @increase_incorrect` could be your culprits.  Have you debugged this by stepping through the individual ASM instructions one at a time ?  Instead of `JL` (Jump if less than) and `JG` (Jump if greater than) try `JB` (Jump if below) and `JA` (Jump if above). `JL` and `JG` are, I believe, for signed comparisons while `JA` and `JB` are for unsigned comparisons. Let me know if this works.

Comment: If you want this to be fun, then don't mix pascal and asm in one routine. Also, learn the platform abi. Not knowing that is another way to kill the fun. Finally, if you want us to analyses something, show it in complete form. What's `numIn`? A parameter? A global? A field of a class? A local? It would be trivially easy to present a complete program. Learning how to ask good questions will also increase your fun levels.

Comment: Read the doc's [Using_Inline_Assembly_Code](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Inline_Assembly_Code), so you know the rules.

Comment: Sorry David, I accidentally missed the top and bottom of the function when I copied it. I'll edit the original post now.

Comment: Please help my understanding. You have this instruction `call @skip` which will be altering the stack; big time, in a major way with what you are doing. Where do you fix the stack from all these calls ?

Comment: Also, `call @skip` makes no sense, that's not a function. You might have wanted `jmp`.

Comment: @Jester Just put in my order for an [AFDB](http://zapatopi.net/afdb/)

Comment: I admit, I was wrong using `call`, I wasn't sure what to do, so I used the first thing I found in some example code.

Comment: Start with analyzing the disassembled code of a pascal function.

Comment: I've run through the program line by line and the part that appears to be the problem is `cmp eax,'9'` and the subsequent `ja @increase_incorrect`. Even when a character is in 0-9, this code doesn't work correctly and the number of invalid characters is still increased.

Comment: What was the byte retrieved before you did the `cmp eax,'9'` ? Was it in the range 80h thru FFh ?

Comment: It's pretty pointless looking at this as it stands, with that `call`.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry David. I'll just change that to jmp. Does that fix your problems with it?

Comment: Ok, I've updated the code in the original post to match what I have now. It's still operating functionally identically to what was there before, just now I don't use any unusable registers.

Also, this is my first real attempt at Assembly in Delphi, so I probably am going to get some fairly obvious stuff wrong.

Comment: @JamEngulfer221: Yes, that happens if you are new. But if you ask for help, it might make sense to actually listen to the advice given.

Comment: But, I did though. I followed the advice that was given and it worked better than it did before. I changed my code based upon the suggestions left here (unless that differs from your definition of listening to advice)

Comment: Starting from the original code, my advice resolves the problems. Of course I'm assuming string = ansistring. But you don't have the original code anymore so who knows what your code is like now?

Comment: How to get what code I have now: Step 1) View the edit history of the original post and get the original code. Step 2) Turn 'call' into 'imp' as per advice. Step 3) Follow advice in first part of your answer. Step 4) Follow advice in second part of your answer. Done! It's almost as if I edited my code as per the advice I was given and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You don't need counting non-digits chars. When you encounter the very first non-digit - you have your boolean answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right off the bat, this is wrong:

```
lea ecx,[numIn]
```

That loads the address of the local variable `numIn` into the `esi` register. But you want the address of the buffer.

```
mov ecx,numIn
```

Of course, you'd need to add some code to deal with the empty string, for which `numIn` is `nil`.

And I think it is asking for trouble to mix Pascal and asm in one function. The compiler doesn't know what your asm code is doing to the registers, and vice versa. Don't mix Pascal and asm like that.

---

I wonder what this code is trying to achieve:

```
if(incorrectCharacters > 0) then begin
  isValid := true;
end else begin
  isValid := false;
end;

checkInteger := isValid;
```

Don't you mean:

```
checkInteger := incorrectCharacters > 0;
```

Do that and remove the `isValid` variable.

---

If you want the code to perform well, you should exit as soon as you find one invalid character. It is pointless to count how many there are. Once you've found one, you need to bail out.

I'd write it like this:

```
function checkInteger(const numIn : AnsiString) : Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to Length(numIn) do
    if (numIn[i]<'0') or (numIn[i]>'9') then
    begin
      Result := False;
      exit;
    end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

The compiler turns that into the following:

```
0041A150 56               push esi
0041A151 8BF0             mov esi,eax
0041A153 8BD6             mov edx,esi
0041A155 85D2             test edx,edx
0041A157 7405             jz $0041a15e
0041A159 83EA04           sub edx,$04
0041A15C 8B12             mov edx,[edx]
0041A15E 8BCA             mov ecx,edx
0041A160 85C9             test ecx,ecx
0041A162 7E1A             jle $0041a17e
0041A164 BA01000000       mov edx,$00000001
0041A169 0FB64416FF       movzx eax,[esi+edx-$01]
0041A16E 3C30             cmp al,$30
0041A170 7204             jb $0041a176
0041A172 3C39             cmp al,$39
0041A174 7604             jbe $0041a17a
0041A176 33C0             xor eax,eax
0041A178 5E               pop esi
0041A179 C3               ret
```

That's a lot better than what you managed. A good exercise would be to start from here and try to improve it.

Comment: The (probably way too complicated) code using 'isValid' is there because we weren't taught the more efficient way of doing it. (Yeah, 2014 and we're still learning Pascal at college)

Comment: Hmm, if you are still learning Pascal, I wonder if it's the best use of your time to learn inline asm .....

Comment: And about using a mix of pascal and ASM, if it is so dangerous to use, why would there be the capability of using it so easily in the first place? Would there ever actually be a safe way of using it?

Comment: Just because you are allowed to do something doesn't mean it's a good idea to do it. Still, if you insist, go for your life.

Comment: Well, I followed your advice and fixed my code a bit, so now my results (although still kinda wrong) are more consistent. It's picking up invalid characters every time, but it's still getting caught on about half of the numbers

Comment: It worked fine starting from where I started. But you've moved the goalposts now. Having solved the problem once, I don't feel inclined to do so again. I'm sorry I've not been able to help you.

Comment: I'd like to note here that just because it's not the best way of doing it, doesn't mean it's not useful. Actually counting the amount of characters that are incorrect can tell me much more information when debugging than just exiting. It's telling me now that although all non numbers are caught, exactly half of the numbers are caught, a fact I wouldn't know, had I just exited on a wrong character. Also, we learnt Pascal last year. This year we're doing GUIs in Delphi, so I'm not missing out on much by looking into ASM.

Comment: I don't buy that argument at all. If your code is broken, perhaps with a woide char / ansi char error, then it will not work with a fail fast implementation either.

Comment: I didn't say it would. Just that (at least for a beginner) it tells me much more than the 'easier' or 'quicker' option.

Comment: OK, do it your way then. Doesn't sound like I can help you at all.

Comment: Hey, I'd like to apologise for causing so much hassle for you and generally being a bit of a prick. I went through and re-did my code following your advice as close as possible and it eventually worked. I believe it was the fact I was using a String for input and not an AnsiString. Anyway, thank you for the help and I'm sorry for being so difficult.

Comment: No need to apologise. I was quite robust with you!!  ;-)  Which version of Delphi do you use?

Comment: The version we have installed here is 'Embarcadero® Delphi® XE Version 15.0.3953.35171'. It's quite an old version, so we ended up with the college not having enough license keys for everyone to do the Computing exam at once :/

Comment: OK. To make your code work, you need to use 8 bit text, `AnsiString`. As you can see I did when I wrote code. Or use `UnicodeString` (aka `string`) and do word based iteration rather than byte based.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to throw my solution which takes full advantage of using ESI register in:

```
function HasNonDigits(const S: AnsiString): Boolean;
asm
        push    esi

        { ecx <- LStrLen(S) }
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [S-4]

        lea     esi, [S]
        cld               { for illustrative purpose, see the note }
@loop:
        lodsb             { al <- [esi]; esi <- esi+1; ecx <- ecx-1 }
        cmp     al, '0'
        jl      @true
        cmp     al, '9'
        jg      @true
        loop    @loop

        mov     al, 0     { Ord(False) } 
        jmp     @endp

@true:
        mov     al, 1     { Ord(True) }
@endp:
        pop     esi
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  Tests: array[0..5] of AnsiString = (
    '12345',
    'foo',
    '700',
    'barbar',
    'streisand',
    'f33r'
  );
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := Low(Tests) to High(Tests) do
    OutputDebugString(PChar(Format('%s -> %s', [
      Tests[I],
      BoolToStr(HasNonDigits(Tests[I]), True)
    ])));
end;
```

To recap, inline assembler code HAVE to comply with the following [conventions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Program_Control#Register_saving_conventions):

> Procedures and functions must preserve the EBX, ESI, EDI, and EBP
>   registers, but can modify the EAX, EDX, and ECX registers. When
>   implementing a constructor or destructor in assembler, be sure to
>   preserve the DL register. Procedures and functions are invoked with
>   the assumption that the CPU's direction flag is cleared (corresponding
>   to a CLD instruction) and must return with the direction flag cleared.

Comment: This looks quite clean and clear. Note that adding `const` doesn't change how the parameter is passed. The pointer to the string still comes in the eax register. Personally I'd not bother referring to `S` here and would use `eax` directly which I find clearer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, fixed that, thanks. Explicit reference to parameter symbol might be useful, tho, esp. for novice.

Comment: That's one of those things that looks appealing, but then comes back to bite you. In my view. Here, `S` arrives in `eax`, a volatile register. Suppose you modify `eax` but subsequently refer to `S`. You are in for a shock. Can be hard to track down. So personally I tend to write a comment at the top of the routine explaining register usage and then reference parameters using register names.